# How to justify all links in my div over the full width?

Tags: html, css

I have this index menu, and i'm trying to make all the links in the div have the same width, so they always fill the container.

The result should be: At start of div, we have `A` and at the end we have Z (or the last element in the div)

As you can see it doesn't stretch at the moment. Is there some way to do it?

```css
div{
width:100%;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
}

div a{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=A">A</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=B">B</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=C">C</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=D">D</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=E">E</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=F">F</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=G">G</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=H">H</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=I">I</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=J">J</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=K">K</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=L">L</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=M">M</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=N">N</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=O">O</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=P">P</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=Q">Q</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=R">R</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=S">S</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=T">T</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=U">U</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=V">V</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=W">W</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=X">X</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=Y">Y</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=Z">Z</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use flexbox (`display: flex`) in combination with `justify-content: space-between;` on your div.

```css
div{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div a{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=A">A</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=B">B</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=C">C</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=D">D</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=E">E</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=F">F</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=G">G</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=H">H</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=I">I</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=J">J</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=K">K</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=L">L</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=M">M</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=N">N</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=O">O</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=P">P</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=Q">Q</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=R">R</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=S">S</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=T">T</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=U">U</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=V">V</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=W">W</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=X">X</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=Y">Y</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=Z">Z</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

these rules will do:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
```

```css
div{
width:100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

div a{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=A">A</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=B">B</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=C">C</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=D">D</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=E">E</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=F">F</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=G">G</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=H">H</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=I">I</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=J">J</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=K">K</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=L">L</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=M">M</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=N">N</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=O">O</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=P">P</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=Q">Q</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=R">R</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=S">S</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=T">T</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=U">U</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=V">V</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=W">W</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=X">X</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=Y">Y</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=Z">Z</a>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no reason for `display: block;` in the `div` rule now ;).

Comment: i forgot to remove. my bad

Answer (score 1):

I think in this situation is better to use flex, so it could be something like :

Same html file :

```
<div>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=A">A</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=B">B</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=C">C</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=D">D</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=E">E</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=F">F</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=G">G</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=H">H</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=I">I</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=J">J</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=K">K</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=L">L</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=M">M</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=N">N</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=O">O</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=P">P</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=Q">Q</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=R">R</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=S">S</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=T">T</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=U">U</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=V">V</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=W">W</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=X">X</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=Y">Y</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=Z">Z</a>
</div>
```

But the css have to be :

```
div{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
}

div a{
  flex-grow:1;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

So flex-grow allow you to do this but 1 is the magic number, according to its definition :

> If all items have flex-grow set to 1, the remaining space in the
>   container will be distributed equally to all children.

I hope it can helps you.

Comment: Ah yes, this solution uses up any space between elements instead of dividing it. Well placed!

Comment: @Roberrrt yepp :)!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to make something like a Menu, which always adapts to the length of the div.

My idea is to set the width of the `<a></a>` elements 
with the formula: 100 devided by the number of elements.

But thats not the best way I think.

```
div a{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 3.5%;
}
```

Maybe this could help you :U

Comment: So, what happens if I decide to remove a link item?